# Calculate the probability of rolling five or more numbers larger than or equal to five in six rolls of a fair die.

Tags: probability

> Calculate the probability of rolling five or more numbers larger than
> or equal to five in six rolls of a fair die.

#### Attempt

This looks like we need to apply the Binomial distribution. If we let $X$ to be the number of rolls to obtain a $5$ or a $6$, then we want to evaluate $P(X \geq 5)$. We know the probaility to obtain and 5 or a 6 is

$$ p = \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3} $$

Thus,

$$ P(X \geq 5) = P(X=5) + P(X=6) = {6 \choose 5 } (1/3)^5 (2/3)^1 + {6 \choose 6} (1/3)^6 (2/3)^0 $$

Is this correct?

Comment: The exponent of $2/3$ should be $1$ and not $2$, otherwise it is perfect.

Comment: fixed it. it was typo

Comment: In R: `sum(dbinom(5:6, 6, 1/3))` returns 0.01783265. Simulation of a million 6-roll experiments: `x = replicate(10^6, sum((sample(1:6, 6, rep=T)>=5))); mean(x >= 5)` gives approximation 0.017802 accurate to several places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100 percent sure, but this is as Bernoulli experiment problem. The probability of a success is 1/3 as you have figured out. Using the general form, ${n \choose r}(1/3)^r(2/3)^{n-r}.$

Going to your solution, it seems that it is true since you are trying to find the probability of rolling more than five on at least 5 rolls out of 6.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Fixed your math formatting. Maybe take a peek at how I did it--as your first lesson using Math Jax.